# jquery addClass() function

Tags: jquery, css, click

This is the css i'm trying to apply to all the keywords

```
#showKeywords {
    background-color:#5B1762;
}
```

What i want to do is when you click the showKeywords button the keywords are highlighted.  However instead of highlighting the keywords it applies the css style to the button.  I notice that the id of the button and the name of the css style are the same.  How can I change the .keyword class without changing the button (showKeywords) style

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showKeywords").click(function() {
        $(".keyword").addClass("showKeywords");
    });
```

```
<div id="menuDiv">
    <span id="showVariables" class="button">Variables</span>
    <span id="showKeywords" class="button">Keywords</span>
</div>
<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span class="keyword">public</span> 
<span class="keyword">static</span>
<span class="keyword">void</span> main(String args[]) {
```

I'm not allowed to change the name of the #showKeywords or I would have done that.

Comment: that isn't a class - that's an id.

Comment: You don't actually have a "showKeywords" class in your stylesheet (not one that we can see anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
#showKeywords {
    background-color:#5B1762;
}
```

to

```
.showKeywords {
    background-color:#5B1762;
}
```

The '#' character in front of `showKeywords` means that the styles are only shown for an element with an id of 'showKeyWords.' What you want is a CSS **class**, designated with a period.

## EDIT

If you aren't allowed to change the existing CSS, you'll have to add a style tag to your HTML. Put the following code inside that page's `<head>` tag, or at the top of the file if you're using a layout page.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .showKeywords {
        background-color:#5B1762;
    }
</style>
```

And finally, if you would like to prevent the showKeyWords button from being that color as well, just change the id of the `showKeyWords` button in your HTML and JavaScript to something different.

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the existing css :c

Comment: Yea I just added existing css as a class and it works.